# Flutter scrape Google Shopping

Tags: flutter, dart, web-crawler, google-shopping

I am trying to get a product price by searching for the product in Google Shopping with a given `title` and `storeName`.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43874789/scrape-google-shopping-with-python) question on SO, which explains how you would do it with Python. How can something like this be done with **Flutter**?

Also like I said, is there any way to select the store?

I couldn't find anything on this. Any help is appreciated. Let me know if you need any more info!

I tried it like this:

```
Future<void> getGoogleShoppingResult() async {
  const String requestUrl =
      'https://www.google.com/search?q=minecraft+toys&tbm=shop';

  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(requestUrl));
  dom.Document document = parser.parse(response.body);

  final elements = document.querySelectorAll(
    'div.sh-np__product-title.translate-content',
  );
  print(elements.first.innerHtml);
}
```

With this I tried to get the `title` of the first found product. But this never finds any product, even though I copied the `selector` from Google Shopping.

Answer (score 1):

You should use these packages:

webview_flutter 
[http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) 
[html](https://pub.dev/packages/html)

And wait till JavaScript has been loaded.

This tutorial can help:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EHk66k___EY

The code snippet:

```dart
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'package:html/dom.dart' as dom;

class WebViewPageExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const WebViewPageExample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<WebViewPageExample> createState() => _WebViewPageExampleState();
}

class _WebViewPageExampleState extends State<WebViewPageExample> {
  late WebViewController _controller;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WebView(
      onWebViewCreated: _onWebViewCreated,
      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      initialUrl: "https://www.google.com/search?q=minecraft+toys&tbm=shop",
      onPageFinished: _onPageFinished,
    );
  }

  void _onWebViewCreated(WebViewController controller) {
    _controller = controller;
  }

  Future _onPageFinished(String url) async {
    final html = await _controller.runJavascriptReturningResult(
        "new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document);");

    final div = dom.Document.html(html)
        .querySelectorAll('div.sh-np__product-title.translate-content');

    log('Count: ${div.length}');
  }
}
```

Comment: could you elaborate on this? And how do I *wait till javascript is loaded* ? :)

Comment: I updated my question. I tried it with your help, but couldn't make it work

Comment: @Chris added code snippet

Comment: awesome thank you. Can this also be done without a `WebView`?

Comment: I do not know, sorry. But why does it bothers you?

Comment: I would need to make these requests in the background. And having a `WebView` Widget for that feels wrong.

Comment: Look at [puppeteer](https://pub.dev/packages/puppeteer) and read its limitation.